# linq to sql to linq to object(date conversion)

Tags: linq, linq-to-sql, linq-to-objects

can some one convert it into linq to sql and remove let somehow?

```
 Func<string, DateTime?> tryToGetDate = value =>
        {
            DateTime dateValue;
            return DateTime.TryParse(value, out dateValue)
                ? (DateTime?)dateValue
                : null;
        };

  var dates = (from bk in _context.BookDetails
                             join bkcategories in _context.BookCategories
                             on bk.BookId equals bkcategories.BookId
                             where bkcategories.CategoryId == Convert.ToInt64(categoryid)
                             let dateValue = tryToGetDate(bk.PublishedDate)
                             where dateValue != null && (DateTime)dateValue >= twomonths && (DateTime)dateValue <= today
                             orderby bk.PublishedDate descending, bk.BookId
                             select bk).Take(2).ToList();
```

Answer (score 0):

```
var dates = (from bk in _context.BookDetails
                             join bkcategories in _context.BookCategories
                             on bk.BookId equals bkcategories.BookId
                             where bkcategories.CategoryId == Convert.ToInt64(categoryid)
                             where SqlFunctions.IsDate(bk.PublishedDate.ToString())==1 && bk.PublishedDate >= twomonths && bk.PublishedDate <= today
                             orderby bk.PublishedDate descending, bk.BookId
                             select bk).Take(2).ToList();
```